# What style are these notebook covers illustrations?

Tags: style-identification

I would like to know what style is this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mix of old and new here so I'm not sure there is a specific name for it but it's a *modern take on Art Deco*. **Neo Art Deco** and **New Art Deco** are terms that seem used more commonly for that kind of revival in the field of interior decoration.

"Gilt tooled" or "gilded" book covers refers to a technique that looks like foil/embossing, and which was popular in the late 1800s early 1900s (refered to as The Gilded Age in US history). That is represented with the use of few colors in your examples. If you look for those, you will see a lot of Art Deco style covers, which accounts for the centered composition and in which you can find many of the major characteristics.

> [Art Deco's] major characteristics include:
>
> - Heavy geometric influences
> - Triangular shapes
> - Zigzags
> - Trapezoidal shapes
> - Straight and smooth lines
> - Loud, vibrant, and even kitschy colors
> - Streamlined and sleek forms
> - Sunburst or sunrise motifs
> - Exaggerated curves
> - Hard edges
> - Low reliefs
> - Stepped forms
> - Chevron (inverted, V-shaped mark) arrangements
> - Ziggurat patterns
> - Stylized, floral patterns

https://creativemarket.com/blog/art-deco-design-style-examples

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Vector Line Art

I don't know whether to give it a name beyond Vector illustration, but after a search in Google several results appear as [**Vector Line Art**](https://www.google.com/search?q=vector%20line%20art&hl=es&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CfPfjupH9LDHIjg6IFb4B-Dh3oaE7uYqCUdHjX_12PELd10HsRpAMGox8eB3gFZhJYLBLkEmaw_1sIfmy3IF8BHhEK_1SoSCTogVvgH4OHeEYeF6UuZmK6vKhIJhoTu5ioJR0cRYZPQ1wGQeqwqEgmNf_1Y8Qt3XQRHuF9X1ZPLx6SoSCexGkAwajHx4EWLuKLWIArrGKhIJHeAVmElgsEsRKCOV0cmPJFEqEgmQSZrD-wh-bBFXxW_1P5BXLUyoSCbcgXwEeEQr9EXC0pTjh7ONg&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz95iw4Y3fAhVEJhoKHbT0DlgQ9C96BAgBEBs&biw=1749&bih=1164&dpr=1).

[image: Freepick]

*[Freepick.com](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/line-art-with-abstract-shapes_829894.htm)*

[image]

[*Freepick.com*](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-cairo-skyline-with-lineal-style_2729132.htm#term=lineart&page=1&position=30)

[image: thinline]

*[123rf.com](https://www.123rf.com/stock-photo/magical_world_imagination_thin_line.html?oriSearch=magical%20world%20imagination&sti=m9hxvtsogpo0wev4v5%7C&mediapopup=44436532)*

[image: Line Style]

[*Canstockphoto.com*](https://www.canstockphoto.com/cleaning-supplies-line-style-30936078.html)